# QNetworkAccessManager - No such signal

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

```
void MainWindow::handleGetReply(QNetworkReply  *reply)
{
    qDebug() << reply;
}

void MainWindow::on_getDetailsButton_clicked()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(
                manager,
                SIGNAL(finished(QNetwokReply *reply)),
                this,
                SLOT(handleGetReply(QNetworkReply*)));
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://google.com")));
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work, and I have the following message:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QNetworkAccessManager::finished(QNetwokReply *reply) in ..\MyApplication\mainwindow.cpp:63
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

Comment: You are missing an 'r' in the word QNetworkReply in your signal.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. Typos are my #1 enemy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect the signal using the SIGNAL and SLOT macros, you only need to pass the type of data that the signal transports, in your case it should be:

```
connect(manager, 
        SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), 
        this, 
        SLOT(handleGetReply(QNetworkReply*)));
```

Although it is advisable to use the [new syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax):

```
connect(manager, 
        &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, 
        this, 
        &MainWindow::handleGetReply);
```

Comment: Awesome, the new syntax woks! The first example still doesn't work for me though

Comment: Edit the 1st example based on the comment to the OP